# ice:selectInputDate - valueChangeListener attribut not working when date entered manually

Tags: jsf, icefaces, valuechangelistener

When I try to enter dates manually in tag that uses **ice:selectInputDate**, the **valueChangeListener**  attribute doesnt work. When I click on the calendar symbol and select the date, the valueChangeListener works fine and my debug is redirected at proper method in bean.

Can anyone suggest on how to use **valueChangeListener** for this **ice:selectInputDate** when date is entered manually.

Answer (score 0):

ValueChangeListener is not necessary

```
<ice:selectInputDate id="d1" renderMonthAsDropdown="true"
                     renderYearAsDropdown="true"
                     rendered="true"
                     renderAsPopup="true"
                     value="#{bean.myoDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
 </ice:selectInputDate>
```

make sure your panel/grid is enclosed with from

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
But I want to avoid

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
But I want to avoid user to enter incorrect dates viz.,, text instead of number.
I am getting the default error message displayed but I want to set customized error message depending the text entered and other validations.
It works fine when I select the date from the calendar popup.

Comment: It wont be in sync to rest of the application. Hence this solution was called off initially itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ajax events as below

```
   <ice:selectInputDate id="d1" renderMonthAsDropdown="true"
                     renderYearAsDropdown="true"
                     valueChangeListener ="#{yourbean.yourValueChangeListener}"
                     rendered="true"
                     renderAsPopup="true"
                     value="#{bean.myoDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                    <ace:ajax event="dateTextChange" execute="@this" />
                    <ace:ajax event="dateSelect" execute="@this" />
  </ice:selectInputDate>
```